# How to remove KDE stuff from software updater

Tags: updates, kde

Hi I had kde installed besides unity. I didn't like it so I've uninstalled kde.

But even after that I still get updates for some kde stuff (konqueror, kate, okular, akonadi and many many things...)

I don't see any ppa related to kde in software updater. How do I remove it completely? Or at least stop getting those updates?

Answer (score 0):

kubuntu-desktop or kubuntu-full are metapackages. Uninstall these packages does not uninstall kde packages. You need to uninstall all packages manually...

You can view the list of installed programs by looking at my /var/log/apt/history.log.*. In these files you can locate the packages installed in the kubuntu install and remove they.